# How do I stop my iPad from wrongly auto correcting my name?

Tags: autocorrect

When I set up my iPad last year I entered my name correctly. The iPad wrongly autocorrected it to Alien. Now anyone who gets an email from me is informed its from Alien. Irritating. I don't want to turn off autocorrect though as its useful.

Comment: Check your contacts. Are you there under 'Alien'?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If so, please choose an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you entered your name incorrectly.

**If your name is entered incorrectly as a contact then:**

1. Click on `Contacts`
2. Scroll down until you see 'Alien'
3. Click on the contact
4. Click `Edit`
5. Change the name

**If you entered your name incorrectly only in your email account settings:**

1. Go to `Settings` > `Mail, Contacts, Calendars`
2. In the `ACCOUNTS` section, click on the account that has the incorrect information (e.g. `Gmail`)
3. Click on `Account`
4. Change the `Name` associated with that email account.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when you type 'Aileen' it is always autocorrected to 'Alien'?

My favourite way to fix this is to define a shortcut as the result of a shortcut is never autocorrected.

Go to Settings > General > Keyboards and "Add New Shortcut..." Set the "Phrase" to 'Aileen ' and make the shortcut something uncommon - I use ';' followed by a letter - so choose ';a' as a shortcut.

Now when you want to type your name then type ';a' and it will be replaced with "Aileen" and never corrected to anything else. As a benefit it is faster to type.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how to change your name:

1. Open the Contacts app
2. Scroll to your name
3. Click edit
4. Edit your name

This should fix your autocorrect issue.

Comment: Based on the vague wording of the question, this is a very valid answer. Not sure why this was downvoted.